# LINQ with sub select query using sum and group by?

Tags: linq, group-by, subquery, sum

Can anyone help me with a LINQ query. I have converted most of it but i have a sub query in the stored procedure and i can't figure out how to do it..

basically this is the old stored procedure (truncated for ease)

```
 SELECT  M.Period AS 'Period' ,
            C.Code AS 'Group' ,
            C.ClientCode AS 'Code' ,
            C.ClientName AS 'Name' ,
            ( SELECT    SUM(Amount) AS Expr1
              FROM      M
              WHERE     ( ClientCode = C.ClientCode )
              GROUP BY  ClientCode
            ) AS 'Amount' ,
```

As you can see from above the sub query is like so

```
              SELECT    SUM(Amount) AS Expr1
              FROM      M
              WHERE     ( ClientCode = C.ClientCode )
              GROUP BY  ClientCode
            ) AS 'Amount'
```

So i have done all my joins and i have this so far and it works.

```
 var test = from c in C join h in H on c.Code 
            equals h.Code join m in M on c.ClientCode   
            equals m.ClientCode 
            select new 
            { 
                Period=m.Period,
                Group=c.Code,
                Code= c.ClientCode,
                Name= c.ClientName,
                <-- Here is where i need the sub select query above -->
            };
```

But i am at a loss of how to do the subquery. The name of the column will be Amount as you are able to see in the old stored procedure.

I would appreciate any feedback or help

THanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im not sure on that last part of your SQL query but I am assuming something like this

```
SELECT  M.Period AS 'Period' ,
C.Code AS 'Group' ,
C.ClientCode AS 'Code' ,
C.ClientName AS 'Name' ,
( SELECT    SUM(Amount) AS Expr1
  FROM      M
  WHERE     ( ClientCode = C.ClientCode )
  GROUP BY  ClientCode
) AS 'Amount' 
from C inner join M on C.ClientCode = M.ClientCode
```

so your LINQ will be this

```
var test = from c in db.C
select new {
  Period = c.M.Period,
  Group = c.Code,
  Code = c.ClientCode,
  Name = c.ClientName,
  Amount = (System.Int32)
    ((from m0 in db.M
    where
      m0.ClientCode == c.ClientCode
    group m0 by new {
      m0.ClientCode
    } into g
    select new {
      Expr1 = (System.Int32)g.Sum(p => p.Amount)
    }).First().Expr1)
}
```

Comment: Wow! THanks Raymund!! Yep just put it in .. and it works :-) Thanks....  Would you be so kind as to explain why i need Expr1 and then after the First() another Expr1? Of course if i remove the EXPR1 it fails  .. but i don't fully understand why its there :-)

Comment: Expr1 is the variable that computes the sum and the second Expr1 exposes it